# Dynamic website-navigation (one file for all pages) in a filesystem - without webserver

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello i have a website without a webserver in a windows-filesystem.
Now i will refactor the old navigation and plan to use only one navigation-file in a seperate folder.

In the navigation-folder the links should be set the links in dependency to the root folder. The root folder have no specific name, but in the root folder there is always a start.html.

For e.g.

```
c:\test\start.html is the root file 
c:\test\foo\foo.html is another file
c:\test\bar\bar.html is another file
c:\test\bar\foobar\foobar.html is another file
```

all this files include the navigation.js where the links are defined.

```
     'text' : 'start',
     'a_attr' : { 'href': 'start.html'}

     'text' : 'foo',
     'a_attr' : { 'href': 'foo/foo.html'},

     'text' : 'bar',
     'a_attr' : { 'href': 'bar/bar.html'},

     'text' : 'foobar',
     'a_attr' : { 'href': 'bar/foobar/foobar.html'},
```

That **works fine** when I include this navigation in the **start.html**. The all links have the correct relation.

But when I include this in the foo.html then the links have a wrong relation. Because start.html isn't in the foo-folder.

So the Question, is there a common way to get the root folder and set the navigation-links dynamicly?
Or is it possible to check in which folder-deep in reference to the start.html the current file is?

```
All files in test has folder-deep 0
All files in foo has folder-deep 1
All files in bar has folder-deep 1
All files in foobar has folder-deep 2
```

I can't use absolute links and so there is the need for relative links.
Then when I use absolute links, i can't move the website-folder with all sub-folders too another drive.

And when i use the root-relative link \start.html then the link is related to the drive, thats wrong too.

Comment: to satisfy all your needs without absolute url  you must use different `navigation.js` for each page.

Comment: Is there not another possibilty to check the folder deep in relation to a specific file e.g. start.html?

Can i do so a check with javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i have solved the problem.

The preload time was a factor.

This is the solution.

```
function preloadimages(subFolderDeep){
    var arr=[];
    arr.push(subFolderDeep + "7/e32l?.png");
    var newimages=[], loadedimages=0
    var arr=(typeof arr!="object")? [arr] : arr
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        newimages[i]=new Image()
        newimages[i].src=arr[i];
        i.src = arr[i];
        newimages[i].onload=function(){
            console.log(newimages[0].src);
            console.log(i);
            startNavigation(subFolderDeep);
        }
        newimages[i].onerror=function(){
        console.log(newimages[0].src);
        subFolderDeep = subFolderDeep + "../"
        preloadimages(subFolderDeep);
        }
    }
}

//sample run
preloadimages("");
```

I'am searching for the special 7/e32l?.png in my root-directory. When the image can be load then i have the relative deep from the active-file to the root-directory. This relative deep must be included in the navigation and then i can use one navigation for all files.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have a possible solution but this work's not correct by the first call of the page, or by a reload with crtl+f5

In the root-folder I place a png imgage with a special name for e.g. start.png

Now i call in the navigation.js a function an check if the image exist.

```
function UrlExists(url)
{
   var img = new Image();
   img.src = url;
   if (img.height!= 0){
       k = true;
   }else{k = false}
   return k;
}

function createUrl(x){
    k = "";
    while(x>0){
        k += "../";
    x=x-1;
    }
    return k;
}

var subFolderDeep = "";

x = 8;
while(x>0){
    urlLen = createUrl(x);
    if(UrlExists(urlLen + "start.png")){
        subFolderDeep = urlLen;
        break;
    }
    x=x-1;
}

alert(subFolderDeep);
startNavigation(subFolderDeep);

 'text' : 'start',
 'a_attr' : { 'href': subFolderDeep + 'start.html'}

 'text' : 'foo',
 'a_attr' : { 'href': subFolderDeep + 'foo/foo.html'},

 'text' : 'bar',
 'a_attr' : { 'href': subFolderDeep + 'bar/bar.html'},

 'text' : 'foobar',
 'a_attr' : { 'href': subFolderDeep + 'bar/foobar/foobar.html'},
```

But at the first start the subFolderDeep is even ""; When I refresh the page or when i call a new page with a navigationlink then I get the right subFolderDeep;

I get the correct result too, when I use at the first call the debugger.

For e.g. bar/foobar/foobar I get subFolderDeep = "../../", but at the first call = "";

Ok with the log i see the problem.

At the first call the heigth of the image is 0; By a refresh next call the heigth is 24. Where is the problem?

```
"file:///start.png" navigation.js:6:3
0 navigation.js:7:3
"file:///start.png" navigation.js:6:3
0 navigation.js:7:3
"file:///start.png" navigation.js:6:3
0 navigation.js:7:3
"file:///start.png" navigation.js:6:3
0 navigation.js:7:3
"file:///D:/start.png" navigation.js:6:3
0 navigation.js:7:3
"file:///D:/someFolder/start.png" navigation.js:6:3
0 navigation.js:7:3
**"file:///D:/someFolder/rootFolder-test/start.png" navigation.js:6:3
0 navigation.js:7:3**
"file:///D:/someFolder/rootFolder-test/k/start.png" navigation.js:6:3
0




"file:///start.png" navigation.js:6:3
0 navigation.js:7:3
"file:///start.png" navigation.js:6:3
0 navigation.js:7:3
"file:///start.png" navigation.js:6:3
0 navigation.js:7:3
"file:///start.png" navigation.js:6:3
0 navigation.js:7:3
"file:///D:/start.png" navigation.js:6:3
0 navigation.js:7:3
"file:///D:/someFolder/start.png" navigation.js:6:3
0 navigation.js:7:3
**"file:///D:/someFolder/rootFolder-test/start.png" navigation.js:6:3
24**
```